# transfer learning [resnet18] using PyTorch. Dataset: Dog-Breed-Identification

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, resnet

I am trying to implement a transfer learning approach in PyTorch. This is the dataset that I am using: [Dog-Breed](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification/data)

Here's the step that I am following.

```
1. Load the data and read csv using pandas.
2. Resize (60, 60) the train images and store them as numpy array.
3. Apply stratification and split the train data into 7:1:2 (train:validation:test)
4. use the resnet18 model and train.
```

Location of dataset

```
LABELS_LOCATION = './dataset/labels.csv'
TRAIN_LOCATION = './dataset/train/'
TEST_LOCATION = './dataset/test/'
ROOT_PATH = './dataset/'
```

Reading CSV (labels.csv)

```
def read_csv(csvf):
    # print(pandas.read_csv(csvf).values)
    data=pandas.read_csv(csvf).values
    labels_dict = dict(data)
    idz=list(labels_dict.keys())
    clazz=list(labels_dict.values())
    return labels_dict,idz,clazz
```

I did this because of a constraint which I will mention next when I am loading the data using DataLoader.

```
def class_hashmap(class_arr):
    uniq_clazz = Counter(class_arr)
    class_dict = {}
    for i, j in enumerate(uniq_clazz):
        class_dict[j] = i
    return class_dict

labels, ids, class_names = read_csv(LABELS_LOCATION)
train_images = os.listdir(TRAIN_LOCATION)
class_numbers = class_hashmap(class_names)
```

Next, I resize the image to 60,60 using `opencv`, and store the result as numpy array.

```
resize = []
indexed_labels = []
for t_i in train_images:
    # resize.append(transform.resize(io.imread(TRAIN_LOCATION+t_i), (60, 60, 3)))  # (60,60) is the height and widht; 3 is the number of channels
    resize.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(TRAIN_LOCATION+t_i), (60, 60)).reshape(3, 60, 60))
    indexed_labels.append(class_numbers[labels[t_i.split('.')[0]]])

resize = np.asarray(resize)
print(resize.shape)
```

Here in indexed_labels, I give each label a number.

Next, I split the data into 7:1:2 part

```
X = resize  # numpy array of images [training data]
y = np.array(indexed_labels)  # indexed labels for images [training labels]

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X, y)


for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    X_temp, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]  # split train into train and test [data]
    y_temp, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]  # labels

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.123, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X_temp, y_temp)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X_temp, y_temp):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "VAL:", test_index)
    X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[test_index]  # training and validation data
    y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[test_index]  # training and validation labels
```

Next, I loaded the data from the previous step into torch DataLoaders

```
batch_size = 500
learning_rate = 0.001

train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train))
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

val = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_val), torch.from_numpy(y_val))
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

test = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test), torch.from_numpy(y_test))
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# print(train_loader.size)

dataloaders = {
    'train': train_loader,
    'val': val_loader
}
```

Next, I load the pretrained rensnet model.

```
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

# freeze all model parameters
# for param in model_ft.parameters():
#     param.requires_grad = False

num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_numbers))

if use_gpu:
    model_ft = model_ft.cuda()
    model_ft.fc = model_ft.fc.cuda()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.fc.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler,
                       num_epochs=25)
```

And then I use the train_model, a method described [here](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#training-the-model) in PyTorch's docs.

However, when I run this I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nirvair/Sites/pyTorch/TL.py",
    line 244, in <module>
        num_epochs=25)
      File "/Users/nirvair/Sites/pyTorch/TL.py", line 176, in train_model
        outputs = model(inputs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 224, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 149, in forward
        x = self.avgpool(x)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 224, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/pooling.py", line 505, in forward
        self.padding, self.ceil_mode, self.count_include_pad)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 264, in avg_pool2d
        ceil_mode, count_include_pad)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/_functions/thnn/pooling.py", line 360, in forward
        ctx.ceil_mode, ctx.count_include_pad)
    RuntimeError: Given input size: (512x2x2). Calculated output size: (512x0x0). Output size is too small at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THNN/generic/SpatialAveragePooling.c:64
```

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: please mention the line in which you are getting the error.

Comment: @WasiAhmad Updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your network is too deep for the size of images you are using (60x60). As you know, the CNN layers do produce smaller and smaller feature maps as the input image propagate through the layers. This is because you are not using padding.

The error you have simply says that the next layer is expecting 512 feature maps with a size of 2 pixels by 2 pixels. The actual feature map produced from the forward pass was 512 maps of size 0x0. This mismatch is what triggered the error.

Generally, all stock networks, such as RESNET-18, Inception, etc, require the input images to be of the size 224x224 (at least). You can do this easier using the `torchvision transforms`[1]. You can also use larger image sizes with one exception for the AlexNet which has the size of feature vector hardcoded as explained in my answer in [2].

Bonus Tip: If you are using the network in pre-tained mode, you will need to whiten the data using the parameters in the pytorch documentation at [3].

**Links**

1. http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865203/7387369
3. http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/models.html

Comment: I am not able to do with torch vision transform because I have to stratify the data first before feeding into the model. If there's an alternative to my solution, can you please suggest that?

Comment: You don't need torchvision transforms to resize the images. You are already doing this with OpenCV. You just need to replace the (60, 60) with (224, 224).

I must admit, not having sklearn interfaces in pytorch is it is one of its greatest shortcomings. If you want to do it right, I would suggest writing your own data loader and include parameters for train-test split. If you do it please share the code. It is a common question now.

Comment: After I change the image size to 224, I get an error with loss function. 
`loss.backward()`. It says `RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at /pytorch/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.cu:66`

Comment: This is because a batch size is of 500 is too much for your GPU ram. The input images are much bigger than the 60x60 size you started with. Reduce the batch_size to 16.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add to @Mo Hossny answer that the input shape is not required to be

> 224x224 (at least).

Actually, it should be at least 33x33.
But 224x224 is the recommended shape as the network was initially trained on such input shape. The right thing @Mo Hossny has stated is the dimensionality reduction nature of CNN networks as ResNet18. However, due to the AdaptiveAvgPool2d layer ("adaptive" term allows to pass images larger and smaller than reccomended shape), obtained feature maps just before this layer are teoretically as follows:

```
Input shape    feature maps(input to AdaptiveAvgPool2d)
3x32x32     --> batch_size x 512 x (cannot reduce dimensionality more)
3x33x33     --> batch_size x 512 x 2x2
3x64x64     --> batch_size x 512 x 2x2
3x128x128   --> batch_size x 512 x 4x4
3x224x224   --> batch_size x 512 x 7x7
3x256x256   --> batch_size x 512 x 8x8
```

Experimenting with resnet18 as a model:
`model(torch.rand(1, 3, 33, 33))` works, where
`model(torch.rand(1, 3, 32, 32))` results in `ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 512, 1, 1])`

Therefore, your size ought not to be the problem in that case.